# Writing BeautifulSoup contents to a file

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I recently asked [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14412907/handling-indian-languages-in-beautifulsoup/14412961#14412961) question about encoding Hindi characters in BeautifulSoup.
The answers to that question did solve that issue, however I have another problem.

My code is :

```
import urllib2
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

htmlUrl = "http://archives.ndtv.com/articles/2012-01.html"
FileName = "NDTV_2012_01.txt"

fptr = open(FileName, "w")
fptr.seek(0)

page = urllib2.urlopen(htmlUrl)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page, from_encoding="UTF-8")

li = soup.findAll( 'li')
for link_tag in li:
  hypref = link_tag.find('a').contents[0]
  strhyp = hypref.encode('utf-8')
  fptr.write(strhyp)
  fptr.write("\n")
```

And I get an error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "./ScrapeTemplate.py", line 29, in <module>
hypref = link_tag.find('a').contents[0]
IndexError: list index out of range
```

It seems to work when I substitute `print strhyp` instead of `fptr.write()`. How do I fix this?

**EDIT:** There was a mistake in the code which I didn't spot. Fixed it, but I'm still getting the same error.

Comment: I tried your code, I didn't get any error. What are you trying to achieve? Do want to get the href of the links? Can you post your expected output? Thanks.

Comment: @AnneLagang - Changed the code. The output should be the list of titles in the HTML page, except I'm getting this error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is tripping over the links at the bottom of the page. Skip over these:

```
for link_tag in li:
  contents = link_tag.find('a').contents
  if len(contents) > 0:
    hypref = contents[0]
    strhyp = hypref.encode('utf-8')
    fptr.write(strhyp)
    fptr.write("\n")
```

Comment: Oh, right! I didn't check the whole way in terminal. This works spectacularly, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The cause of your error doesn't have anything to do with writing to a file. It appears that `link_tag.find('a').contents` sometimes returns an empty list and gives an error when you try to get the first item. You can try something like this:

```
for link_tag in li:
    try:
        hypref = link_tag.find('a').contents[0]
    except IndexError:
        print link_tag #print link tag where it couldn't extract the 'a'
        continue
    strhyp = hypref.encode('utf-8')
    fptr.write(strhyp)
    fptr.write("\n")
```

Comment: But the error doesn't appear when I print the same code straight to the terminal, which is why I suspected that the issue is with writing to a file.

Comment: @Kitchi it also happens if you print to terminal (I tried it). Your code is tripping over the links at the bottom of the page (RSS, News Alerts, Mobile etc.)