# How to parse hindi font from html using BeautifulSoup?

Tags: python, utf-8, html-parsing, beautifulsoup, hindi

I want to get the contents of a  tag using using BeautifulSoup.

My code :

```
html= "<html><body><td class="HindiTextGray" align="left" valign="top">
      <br />
      सूरत। सिल्कसिटी सूरत के कपड़ा बाजार की व्यापारिक प्रक्रिया में बड़ा बदलाव देखने को मिल रहा है।<br /> 
      </td></body></html>"


soup = BeautifulSoup(html)
td =soup.find('td')
extra = td.script.extract()
td.table.extract()
td.span.extract()
self.response.write(td.contents)
```

what i want is :

```
    सूरत। सिल्कसिटी सूरत के कपड़ा बाजार की व्यापारिक प्रक्रिया में बड़ा बदलाव देखने को मिल रहा है।
```

but i get :

> [u'\n', 
> , u'\r\n          \u0938\u0942\u0930\u0924\u0964
>   \u0938\u093f\u0932\u094d\u0915\u0938\u093f\u091f\u0940
>   \u0938\u0942\u0930\u0924 \u0915\u0947 \u0915\u092a\u0921\u093c\u093e
>   \u092c\u093e\u091c\u093e\u0930 \u0915\u0940
>   \u0935\u094d\u092f\u093e\u092a\u093e\u0930\u093f\u0915
>   \u092a\u094d\u0930\u0915\u094d\u0930\u093f\u092f\u093e
>   \u092e\u0947\u0902 \u092c\u0921\u093c\u093e
>   \u092c\u0926\u0932\u093e\u0935 \u0926\u0947\u0916\u0928\u0947
>   \u0915\u094b \u092e\u093f\u0932 \u0930\u0939\u093e \u0939\u0948\u0964
>   \u092f\u0939 \u092c\u0926\u0932\u093e\u0935
>   \u0938\u0948\u091f\u093f\u0902\u0917
>   \u0906\u0927\u093e\u0930\u093f\u0924
>   \u0935\u094d\u092f\u093e\u092a\u093e\u0930
>   \u092a\u094d\u0930\u0915\u094d\u0930\u093f\u092f\u093e \u0915\u093e
>   \u0939\u0948\u0964 \u0907\u0938\u092e\u0947\u0902 90
>   \u092b\u0940\u0938\u0926\u0940 \u0915\u092a\u0921\u093c\u093e
>   \u0935\u094d\u092f\u093e\u092a\u093e\u0930\u0940
>   \u0935\u093f\u0936\u094d\u0935\u093e\u0938 \u0930\u0916\u0924\u0947
>   \u0939\u0948\u0902, \u0932\u0947\u0915\u093f\u0928
>   \u0907\u0938\u0915\u0947 \u092e\u0941\u0924\u093e\u092c\u093f\u0915
>   \u0935\u094d\u092f\u093e\u092a\u093e\u0930 \u0915\u0930\u0928\u0947
>   \u0935\u093e\u0932\u094b\u0902 \u0915\u0940
>   \u0938\u0902\u0916\u094d\u092f\u093e \u092e\u0939\u091c 15
>   \u092a\u094d\u0930\u0924\u093f\u0936\u0924 \u0939\u0940
>   \u0939\u0948\u0964', 
> ,

Comment: If you print a list, you'll see its `repr`. Print the items individually if you want encoded text printed.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Handling Indian Languages in BeautifulSoup](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14412907/handling-indian-languages-in-beautifulsoup)

Comment: @karthikr: not really; that question has a UnicodeDecodeError; this one has text that got decoded just fine with a display issue.

Comment: Are those not the characters you wanted? What is the code point for e.g. `सू`—is it not 938?

Comment: @kindall , It is.. But i want to display this code to users.. i have stored this text in datastore as it is.. But i want it to be displayed in hindi. i used  self.response.headers['Content-Type'] = 'text/html; charset=utf-8' but got decode error

Comment: So you've got what you want; your question is actually how to display it. What are you using? Are you trying to `print` the text? Are you displaying it in a GUI? A Web page?

Comment: Hey.. I got it. I used decode('utf-8')... I am displaying it on webpage..